# How to update tkinter window before reaching mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python file that contains:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import time

root = Tk()
scroll_text = ScrolledText(root)
scroll_text.pack()

def task0():
    time.sleep(5) # some code which takes 5 secs
    pass
def task1():
    # some code which takes a few seconds
    pass
def task2():
    # some code which takes a few seconds
    pass
# ...

for i in range(0, 5):
    scroll_text.insert(INSERT, 'program start to do task{0}\n'.format(i))

    if i == 0:
        task0()
    elif i == 1:
        task1()
    elif i == 2:
        task1()
# ...
    
print('Finish')
        
root.mainloop()
```

I expect when program starts immediately see the `program start to do task ..` text in the `tkinter` window and after that start executing functions, each lasting a few seconds.
What should I do to make the events occur in the same order as the code I wrote (ie, first show the task number with `program start to do task ..` to ***show the user the progress of the program*** in the `tkinter` window and then execute functions).

Comment: Have you done any research? There are many questions on this site related to delayed screen updating in tkinter. It's a _very_ common issue.

Comment: @BryanOakley I updated the answer to better present the problem.

Answer (score 1):

TKinter is not updating the window because the mainloop() is blocked from running by your loop. The solution depends on what actual problem you are trying to solve, which isn't clear from a blank loop. If you're simply trying to create a 5-second delay, use tkinter's after() method to schedule your print() command to run later without blocking the mainloop() until then.

Comment: The answer is the same. Tkinter is not updating the window because the mainloop is isn't reached while Python is running sleep(), or any other blocking code that "some code which takes a few seconds" is supposed to stand for. You need to schedule tasks using root.after() if you want the window to appear while the other code runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your window isn't created until `root.mainloop()` is executed. Your programs first waits then creates the window.
What you can do is, add this line:

```
root.after(5000,lambda: print('Finish'))
```

After 5 second(5000 milliseconds), it will call the `lambda` function, which will print.

Comment: I do not want to pause for 5 seconds. I updated the question so that maybe you can better understand the meaning.